# Python insurance rate

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a simple insurance program rate that I can't figure out how to apply in a program. 
My program needs to do:
 *The insurance rate is 0.20 cents for each 1000 dollars.

The thing is that Ive got no clue how to write an expression to make that happen. I'm just starting Python and I thought it would with a if statement or something but is not and in my class I'm not supposed to do very advanced stuff

Thank you

Edit: So, I have to ask for a house price and from that price get the rate. So if the house cost $1000 then the insurance will cost 20 cents. But if the house costs $2000 then the insurance is 40 cents. As it increases $1000 the insurance increases by 0.20. I don't know how to write that

Comment: This isn't a Python question as much as it is a finance question. Please provide more detail so that we can determine how to create an appropriate expression.

Comment: So, I have to ask for a house price and from that price get the rate. So if the house cost $1000 then the insurance will cost 20 cents. But if the house costs $2000 then the insurance is 40 cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def total_cost(i):
    return round(i * 1.0002, 2)
```

Comment: I tried that but when I input i = 1000. The result becomes 1000.199999 instead of 20 cents